# I want to hide <div> section "softdown" if custom field is not specified

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to hide the Div section if the custom field is not selected or empty!

```
<div class="softdown">
  <span class="postdownlink">
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postdownlink', true); ?>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to provide more information with your question. The div that you are attempting to hide, is it softdown?

Comment: Yes, It is softdown bro.

Comment: Did you tried to use jquery or javascript to make that work?

Comment: No. Please tell me how?

Comment: Can you please explain what the Custom Field is? Are you trying to hide div if there is no post data? from `get_post_meta`

Comment: Does that needs to be done on real time or after post request? if let's say you don't have some field filled in in request?

Comment: I want to hide it when there is no need to use the download button on the post ( If I don't enter postdownlink value in the custom field section for that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within PHP, you can check if a variable is empty using a function called `empty`.
So, you could do something like this:

```
<?php if(!empty($iamempty)){ ?>

<h1>I won't be shown</h1>

<? } ?>
```

So, for you to implement this into your code, you could do the following.

```
<?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postdownlink', true))){ ?>

<div class="softdown">
  <span class="postdownlink">
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postdownlink', true); ?>
  </span>
</div>

<? } ?>
```

The above code will only display the div (The HTML content between the `PHP` tags) if the `get_post_meta` returns a value that is not empty.

Comment: @El3magic Not a problem I'm glad I was able to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be done in real time, you can do that this way:

**This can be added to the top of your JS file:**

```
    var inputChange = function (){
        ($('input#photo').val().length === 0) { 
               // Hide the element  On keyup check the value of the input if length is 0 meaning empty hide the div otherwise show.
               $('div.sofdown').hide(); // Using hide()
               //Or using fadeOut();
               $('div.sofdown').fadeOut(1000);
            }
    }
//Initiate to hide the div if there is no text in input.
inputChange();
```

After that initial state will be `hidden`

**This should be add at the end of the JS file**

```
$('input#photo').keyup(function() { 
    //Call function
    inputChange();
}
```

Comment: I think that you may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: It may be, that is fine, it can help anyone else.